# NAS Built With Consumer Grade Components Won't Boot

Tags: boot, nas

I have recently switched out the power supply and boot drive of a NAS I built. I also added a DVD drive and two screws to the motherboard (which have since been removed). After I did this, pressing the power button has no effect.

Parts list: http://pcpartpicker.com/user/john01dav/saved/#view=b96kcf (I replaced the PSU with a CX500, and the DVD and boot drive with the cheapest on at a store near my house -- I can't get the exact model because the computer won't boot)

As per the advice of the Ask Ubuntu chat, I tried the following things (in this order):

1. Ensure that the power supply's switch (and voltage switch (only the old PSU has a voltage switch) are in the proper location
2. Remove nonessential components (disconnect SATA and power from hard drives and DVD drive, there is no video card except that which is built-into the motherboard)
3. Tighten front panel connectors
4. Use the old PSU without remounting it in the case (sitting on my desk)
5. Try another case's power button
6. Try using a screwdriver to boot the computer (this worked once with the old PSU after tightening the 24-pin connector (I couldn't see the screen because I am testing for boot without one, but all fans and appropriate LEDs came on), but, after reconnecting the new one it failed and failed again after reconnecting the old one)

I have not yet tried starting the PSU by jumping it's 24-pin connector as I do not have a wire (or paperclip) with which to do this. I would like, if possible, answers that assume that this was tried and failed as all it does is test for a bad PSU and I don't belive that either PSU is dead because one worked with item number 5 in the list above and the new PSU was apparently tested by the store I bought it from.

Comment: Is the power switch hooked up to the exact correct pins? Is the switch bad? Is there a master on-off switch on the PSU, does it's power cord work, and is the power on?

Comment: @Xen2050 I have no reason to believe that the case power switch cord is on the wrong pins as that was not changed when the issue ocurred. I tried another power button in another case of the same model and a screwdriver - neither works. The PSUs switch is on. I tried two power cords, one of which is brand new and the other was working before the part changes. The outlet is working as it properly charges my laptop.